# How to control the ciphersuites in nmap "ssl-enum-ciphers"

Tags: network, penetration-test, nmap, network-scanners

There is a script for enumerating the TLS versions and ciphersuites ofered by a server provided by nmap. See this [link](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.html).

Is there a way that allow me to specify the verisions and ciphersuites I want to test the server against? or at least know what the script's versions and ciphersuites that it tests the server against?

This is important because the server's answer actually depends on the client offer. So if the server does not support a cipher I want to make sure it is in the client's offered list.

Answer (score 4):

The cipher suites tested within the `ssl-enum-ciphers` lua script are pulled from something called the TLS Cipher Suite Registry, more info [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4).

Looking at the output of running the suggested command for this type of enumeration, `nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 <host>` we see the cipher suites (provided in the aforementioned [Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4)) that are tested during connection initialization were pulled from TLSv1.0, TLSv1.1, TLSv.1.2, but not yet TLSv1.3.

It should be noted, as provided from within the [Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4), that:

> Although TLSv1.3 uses the same cipher suite space as previous
>   versions of TLS, TLSv1.3 cipher suites are defined differently,
>   only specifying the symmetric ciphers, and cannot be used for TLSv1.2.  Similarly, TLSv1.2 and lower cipher suite values cannot be
>   used with TLSv1.3.

So if you are looking for testing only specific cipher suites then perhaps you could try a manual process rather than using the `NSE`. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/109213/how-do-i-list-the-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-a-particular-website-offers) might be a good resource to consult for trying other methods. Otherwise, by referring to the [Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4) you will be able to see all available cipher suites within their respective versions of TLS which will allow you to manually compare with those of the server's.

Hope this helps with what you are looking to accomplish.

---

Additional sources:
 - http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2012/q3/156